# Unexpected Margin on HTML Body on Mobile Devices using Bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, mobile

I am building a Bootstrap site and was hoping the community could help me identify the code fix to eliminate the unwanted margin/padding that occurs when viewing the site on mobile.

I should only be able to scroll down on the body but I can also scroll to the right seeing only white empty space.

I searched the differents Q and A on Stack and could not find a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Not getting properly what you want but this might can help. You can use Viewport meta tag like below

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no">
```

More details can be found on [mozilla.org](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Mozilla/Mobile/Viewport_meta_tag)

Answer (score 0):

Torben's answer for this [Bootstrap - Some kind of margin on mobile devices (only right side)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25887927/bootstrap-some-kind-of-margin-on-mobile-devices-only-right-side) question might help you.

What you need to do is set the overflow-x of HTML and BODY to hidden.

css code:

```
html,body{
overflow-x: hidden;
}
```