# Bootstrap - Some kind of margin on mobile devices (only right side)

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

i created a mobile page with bootstrap, but for some kind the mobile page has a margin or padding on mobile devices on the right side where i can slide to. I deleted some code, but even the most simple structure has it:

```
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-lg-12">
            <div class="navigation"></div>
          </div>
        </div>
    </div><!--container-->

.container {
  max-width:100%;
  padding:0;
  height: 100%;
  width:100%;
}

.navigation {
  height:3.4375em;
  line-height:1em;
  background-color:#E75200;
}
```

I uploaded the test page here:
http://wp1011618.server-he.de/projekte/test/index2.html

I have the feeling that it is because of the col-lg-12 padding, but Bootstrap this can't be Bootstraps intention so I am wondering whats wrong here?

Thanks!

Answer (score 50, accepted):

I figured it out:

```
html, body {
  overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

Solved it for me!

Comment: Do you know why this happens? I had the same issue (only on mobile) and this fix worked. I can't help but wonder why, it wasn't occurring before.

Comment: Thank you so much !

Comment: Ditto all the other comments. Never seen this issue before on mobile sites then suddenly had issue on site I was updating. Thanks anyway.

Comment: you made my day

Comment: Just a warning when using this, if you have any elements using `position: sticky`, it will stop working. See this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47095596/body-overflow-x-hidden-breaks-position-sticky

Answer (score 7):

**.col-lg-12** class has `padding-right: 15px;` and `padding-left: 15px;`, that causes white spaces. Make them 0, than remove `margin-right: -15px;` and `margin-left: -15px;` in **.row** class.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to set the right-padding on your example header, then just do that style in `.container` for example: Padding-Right:12px.

Answer (score 0):

Do you know you don't have bootstrap.min.js file in your js directory? Anyway, the solution is just don't use "col-lg-12" div, "row" will fill 100% of width so why you want this one?

Comment: Because it is the proper way to use the grid layout in bootstrap? In the original page there is 2-column content, so it makes sende to use .col-lg-6 two times then.

Comment: so then you write two .col-lg-6 elements inside .row. Element .col-lg-12 and other have padding to be usefull for content, not for all page container which should fill 100% browser width. Changing paddings and margins inside bootstrap css is not good idea... See this examples: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid there is no .col-lg-12 div to hold columns, they put their just inside .row

Comment: I am not sure if he try to change the style inside the bootstrap css, he just tried to added inline style to the box.

Comment: I do not change anything in the bootstrap.css files. But my page is e.g 80% and margin:0 auto; when used on desktops. but it should be 100% without any space on the right side on mobiles.

Comment: If so try to add margin 0 to the container, it may fix it, auto just centered the box with default margin.