# body { overflow-x: hidden; } breaks position: sticky

Tags: html, css, css-position

I have an element that I am making sticky with position sticky:

```css
#header {
    position: sticky;
    width: 100vw;
    top: 0;
}
```

```html
<app-header id="header"></app-header>
```

And that works fine, but I realised that if I use:

```
body {
  overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

That breaks sticky, and I need to set `body overflow-x` to `hidden`, how can I fix that, with only CSS solution, no JS solutions?

Comment: Note that sticky, by specification, will not work inside element with overflow: hidden or auto. Also, `position: sticky` is an experimental API and should not be used in production, just a heads up (in case you aren't already aware of that) **see:** https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position#sticky

Comment: Yes, wasn't aware of that, thank you for pointing this out

Comment: The only way I was able to fix this was to unset that `overflow-x` with something like `overflow-x: initial;`. A year later and `position: sticky` is no longer experimental and works cross browser (minus good ol' IE) :)

Answer (score 52):

Setting the `overflow-x` property to value `clip` helped me achieve position sticky and prevent scrolling.

Here is more explanation in [this article](https://www.terluinwebdesign.nl/en/css/position-sticky-not-working-try-overflow-clip-not-overflow-hidden/)

Comment: omfg i've been struggling with this for hours now, and your simple solution did the trick for me! Thanks

Comment: it doesn't work in Safari

Comment: Only works in Safari 16+
Anyone with an older version will still be affected.

Answer (score 25):

#### UPDATE:

This has been successfully tested on Safari v12.0.2, Firefox v64.0, and Chrome v71.0.3578.98

Added `position: -webkit-sticky;` for Safari.

---

Unfortunately the spec is not too clear about the implications of `overflow-x: hidden;` on position sticky, but there is a way to fix this. Thankfully there is an issue to hopefully fix this: https://github.com/w3c/csswg-drafts/issues/865.

The **simple solution** is to remove or unset `overflow-x: hidden;` from every ancestor of the element you want to have `position: sticky;`. Then you can have `overflow-x: hidden;` on the body and it will work!

Also double check that you don't have overflow set on both the body and html tags which I posted about more in depth here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54116725/6502003

Here is a pen if you want to play around with it: https://codepen.io/RyanGarant/pen/REYPaJ

```css
/* 
  Try commenting out overflow on body style and uncommenting
  overflow on .overflow-x-hidden class and you will see 
  position sticky stop working!  
*/

body {
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

.overflow-x-hidden {
/*   overflow-x: hidden; */
  border: 1px solid blue;
}

h1 {
  background: palevioletred;
  color: #fff;
  position: -webkit-sticky;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
}

.tall {
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, paleturquoise, white);
  height: 300vh;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="overflow-x-hidden">
  <h1>I want to be sticky!</h1>
  
  <div class="tall"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Currently (Firefox 78, Chrome 84) this doesn't seem to work any more. Verified by toggling the `overflow-x:hidden` property on the body element.

Comment: "The simple solution is to remove or unset overflow-x: hidden; from every ancestor of the element you want to have position: sticky;" Isn't the `body` tag an ancestor of every element anyway?

Comment: Your "both the body and html tags" url links to itself. Is there any more info somewhere becasue I need to have it on both html and body because of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3047337

Comment: Did you see this link I added @FINDarkside? https://stackoverflow.com/a/54116725/6502003

Comment: This does now work. Note that Safari's `html {overflow-x:hidden; }` behavior seems to be different inside an <iframe> (like Codepen is using) than when you view the same page in full window (un-framed)

Comment: OH MY STARS this freakin fixed so many projects
> Also double check that you **don't have overflow set on both the body and html tags**

Answer (score 7):

```
body, html { overflow-x: clip; }
```

This works well with `position: sticky`

Im using `transform: translateX(-100px)` for load animations and `overflow-x:clip` prevents expanding the viewport and showing horizontal scrollbar..

Comment: Yes: for Android it is necessary to declare the two selectors (html + body).

Answer (score 5):

The sticky doesn't work inside element with overflow: hidden or auto. 
Refer to this https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position#sticky

A workaround can be working with this [library](http://leafo.net/sticky-kit/)

Comment: Hmmm, the link you advise the OP to refer to doesn't mention anything about how `position: sticky` will not work inside elements with `overflow: hidden/auto` - the MDN document does, but not at the section you've anchored to. Also, when you repeat what has already been established in the comments it looks like you are just trying to reputation farm.

Comment: Your are right it does but in the upper definition I just corrected, thanks

Comment: Same problem facing how to run both body {overflow-x: hidden} and child is position: sticky

Answer (score 4):

I think you have to fix :

```
body {
  overflow-x: clip;
}
```

I hope this works .

Comment: It works, but only in Safari 16+
All older Safaris are still affected.

Answer (score 2):

My solution is to replace **overflow: hidden** with this:

```
display: flow-root;
overflow: clip;
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this helps, but I struggled with this for mobile (where the page would "overflow" and scroll past the boundaries) for so long and finally fixed it.

I tried the `body {overflow: hidden;}` solution, but it would disable my sticky elements. So I then created a `<div class="container">` that contained all of my other divs of the page inside the `<body>`, and that seemed to do it!

Answer (score 1):

I just want to add this here if anyone runs into a similar issue. `position:sticky` was not working for me because we are applying `overflow-y:scroll` on tablet/mobile screen resolutions. `overflow:` and `position:sticky` do not work together. This [article](https://uxdesign.cc/position-stuck-96c9f55d9526https://uxdesign.cc/position-stuck-96c9f55d9526) explains the 2 workarounds to fix it. I went with setting a fixed height on the table and then hiding the vertical scroll bar with

```
::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 0;  
  background: transparent;  
}::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 0;  
  background: transparent;  /* 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is how I make it work for me:
Create a **parent wrapper/container element** that should contains all your other page elements, and give it a fixed height (mostly `height: 100vh`) with `overflow-y: auto` and `overflow-x: hidden` as it's described in the code/snippet below ..
and make the body `overflow: hidden` to avoid any extra scroll bars ..

This solution may comes with some consequences/restrictions, for example:
if you're used to use the CSS `scroll-behavior` property in the `html` element you will need then to move it to the `#page_wrapper` element instead ..

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.page-wrapper {
  height: 100vh;
  overflow-y: auto;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

.sticky {
  position: sticky;
  left: 0;
  padding: 4px;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: forestgreen;
}

.sticky-header {
  top: 0;
}
.sticky-footer {
  bottom: 0;
}

.long-content {
  padding: 2rem;
  min-height: 100vh;
}

.break-overflow-x {
  min-width: 200vw;
  padding: 2rem;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="page-wrapper">
    <div class="sticky sticky-header"><button>Sticky Header</button></div>
    <div class="long-content">Long vertical content</div>
    <div class="break-overflow-x">Long horizontal content</div>
    <div class="long-content">Long vertical content</div>
    <div class="sticky sticky-footer"><button>Sticky Footer</button></div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score -1):

can you try with the following...

```css
#one { position: sticky; top: 10px; }* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
body{overflow-x: hidden;}
dl > div {
  background: #FFF;
  padding: 24px 0 0 0;
}

dt {
  background: #B8C1C8;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #989EA4;
  border-top: 1px solid #717D85;
  color: #FFF;
  font: bold 18px/21px Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 2px 0 0 12px;
  position: -webkit-sticky;
  position: sticky;
  top: -1px;
}

dd {
  font: bold 20px/45px Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0 0 0 12px;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

dd + dd {
  border-top: 1px solid #CCC;
}
```

```html
<!-- Learn about this code on MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position -->

<dl>
  <div>
    <dt>A</dt>
    <dd>Andrew W.K.</dd>
    <dd>Apparat</dd>
    <dd>Arcade Fire</dd>
    <dd>At The Drive-In</dd>
    <dd>Aziz Ansari</dd>
  </div>
  <div>
    <dt>C</dt>
    <dd>Chromeo</dd>
    <dd>Common</dd>
    <dd>Converge</dd>
    <dd>Crystal Castles</dd>
    <dd>Cursive</dd>
  </div>
  <div>
    <dt>E</dt>
    <dd>Explosions In The Sky</dd>
  </div>
  <div>
    <dt>T</dt>
    <dd>Ted Leo &amp; The Pharmacists</dd>
    <dd>T-Pain</dd>
    <dd>Thrice</dd>
    <dd>TV On The Radio</dd>
    <dd>Two Gallants</dd>
  </div>
</dl>
```

Answer (score -2):

For those who have the same issue. I added `overflow: hidden` to the div below the header holding all the contents.

> ```
>  <div class="header" style="position: sticky;">
>         //navs
>  </div>
>  <div class="content-div" style="overflow: hidden;">
>        //contents 
>  </div>
> ```